# Check for unique phone number before allowed to sign up with parse ios

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've integrated my app with the parse framework and have added a few extra fields during the sign up process, one of those being phone number. I'd like to check to make sure the phone number entered is unique prior to them being allowed to sign up, like parse does for username and email. However, I can't find documentation anywhere on how to do so.

I've tried running a query on PFUser to check if the entered phone number is in the Users table but the query won't work (results are always nil) unless its included in the signUpInBackgroundWithBlock of code. However, putting the query here still uploads the info to parse no matter the results of the query. Has anyone found a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's see the non-working query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be helpful if you share your query but something like the following should probably do the trick:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"phoneNo" equalTo:@"0123456"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.

        if (objects.count == 0) {

            //Allow Number to be saved

        } else {

            //Give warning that the number is already in use

        }

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Asad Jamal Malik. I was doing a PFUser.query() and it appears that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "beforeSave" trigger that validates the phone number uniqueness. The Parse.com documentation has some good examples.

[Parse.com documentaion](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers)

Comment: Thanks @picciano. The code from Asad below worked but it looks like "beforeSave" could also do the trick. I just need to test it out, as I'm not familiar with it. Thanks though!

Comment: Using a server side verification is the way to go, i doubt its a good idea to allow users to make search by phone numbers in your database, better prohibit this action for users. Then use master key on cloud code to do the search.